# Working in Chrome, but not working in I.E. and Firefox. CSS/STYLE/HTML/PHP

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

I can't figure out how to fix this annoying problem. Searched and tested a lot but nothing works.

Well, I want everything to look like the first image Google Chrome. In I.E. the background is different, the header is not in the center. In Firefox the boxes are not set correctly. I want 2 boxes in every row.

I don't know why this is happening.

I don't get why I.E. is still on the web for download.. Terrible browser

Can someone help me out?

Chrome:

[image]

Firefox:

[image]

I.E.

[image]

Here you can see index.php

HTML/PHP

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta name="generator" content="HTML Tidy for Linux (vers 6 November 2007), see www.w3.org" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<link rel="icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link href="includes/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>-</title>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
#title{color:red; padding-bottom: 240px; padding-left: 25px;}
#desc{color:blue; padding-bottom: 135px; padding-left: 5px;}
/*]]>*/
</style>

<style type="text/css">
/*<![CDATA[*/
 div.c1 {width: 953px}
/*]]>*/
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="header navpos c1" id="nav">
            <table summary="header" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="home"><a href="index.html"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="about"><a href="manage.html"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="contact"><a href="contact.html"></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="twitter"><a href="index.html"><img src="includes/images/f_logo.png" alt="** PLEASE DESCRIBE THIS IMAGE **" /></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <ul>
                            <li class="facebook"><a href="index.html"><img src="includes/images/t_logo.png" alt="link to Syndicate Plus Twitter" /></a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box c1">
        <?php while($products = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {?>
        <table style="float: left;" width="473" align="left" background="includes/images/box.gif" width="473" height="285">
            <tr>
                <td width="35%" height="100%" id="title"><?php echo $products['products'];?></td>
                <td width="70%" height="100%" id="desc"><?php echo $products['description'];?></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    <?php
    }       
    ?>
    </div>
    <div class="footer"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here you can see style.css
CSS***

```
* {
margin : 0;
padding : 0;
}
html {
background-image : url(images/web_bg.png);
}
body {
width : 953px;
margin : auto;
}
img {
border : 0;
}
A:link {
text-decoration : none;
color : #0087dc;
}
A:visited {
text-decoration : none;
color : #0087dc;
}
A:hover {
text-decoration : none;
color : #0087dc;
}
a:active, a:focus {
outline : 0;
}
a {
outline : none;
}
.header {
background-image : url(images/header_bg.png);
width : 953px;
margin : auto;
}
.footer {
background-image : url(images/bot_new.png);
min-height : 229px;
max-height : 229px;
position: relative;
}
#nav {
float : left;
}
#nav li {
float : left;
list-style-type : none;
}
#nav .home a {
margin-left : -20px;
margin-top : 25px;
display : block;
background-image : url(images/header_home.png);
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 400px;
height : 54px;
}
#nav .about a {
margin-left : 300px;
margin-top : 30px;
display : block;
background-image : url(images/header_about.png);
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 64px;
height : 13px;
}
#nav .contact a {
margin-left : 20px;
margin-top : 30px;
display : block;
background-image : url(images/header_contact.png);
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 64px;
height : 13px;
}
#nav .twitter a {
margin-left : 40px;
margin-top : 30px;
display : block;
background-image : url(images/t_logo.png);
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 26px;
height : 26px;
}
#nav .facebook a {
margin-left : 5px;
margin-top : 30px;
display : block;
background-image : url(images/f_logo.png);
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 26px;
height : 26px;
}
#nav .home a:hover {
margin-left : -20px;
margin-top : 25px;
background : url(images/header_home_light.png);
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 400px;
height : 54px;
}
#nav .about a:hover {
margin-left : 300px;
margin-top : 30px;
background : url(images/header_about_light.png);
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 64px;
height : 13px;
}
#nav .contact a:hover {
margin-left : 20px;
margin-top : 30px;
background : url(images/header_contact_light.png);
background-repeat : no-repeat;
width : 64px;
height : 13px;
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is your desired effect and what isn't working? It's hard to tell just by looking at screenshots.

Comment: According to the screen shots it actually looks like Chrome and IE are working and Firefox is the bad stepchild. Can you describe the problem with greater detail and accuracy, and if at all possible leave your prejudices out of it?

Comment: Well, I want everything to look like the first image *Google Chrome*. In I.E. the background is different, the header is not in the center. In Firefox the boxes are not set correctly. I want 2 boxes in every row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the header, content and footer in a `<div>` of constant width to force the next line at some point.

```
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">header</div>
  <div id="content">
      <script type="text/javascript">
        for (i=0;i<5;i++) { // example in javascript
          document.write("<div style='float:left;width:80px;height:80px;background-color:blue;margin:2px;'></div>");
        }
      </script>
  </div>     
  <div id="footer">footer</div>    
</div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body {
   text-align:center;
}
#wrapper {
    background-color:#eee;
    width:300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align:left;
}
#header {
    background-color:red;
}
#content {
}
#footer {
    clear:both;
    background-color:green;
}
```

**Working code & result:** http://jsfiddle.net/fsHd5/3/

Comment: Worked for I.E. but everything is aligned to left in I.E..
Nothing happened in Firefox. Got any more tips?

Comment: @F4LLCON style="margin: auto 0;" centers the outer div

Comment: <div style="width:953px; margin: auto 0;"> this right? No effect at all.. That's the strange part, I tried this before did not work. It's like the code hates me

Comment: For this solution as well, you'll need to remove the body width and margins that you set. Otherwise you'll likely be centering a 950px block in a 953px block, not much difference.

Comment: In I.E. it's now in the center. But why does the background image change style every time i refresh? Random, it shows background image, next time it does not show, next time it shows a part of it. After hitting F5 in I.E.

In Firefox still no effect.

Comment: @F4LLCON like Toast wrote, remove all the margins and widths you've set before. The only width you need is the width of the outer DIV and add background-image to this DIV.

Comment: Well thanks anyways, I'm going to rewrite the code in proper way. And see what the results are now with this information in hand.

Comment: @F4LLCON You might start from the jsfiddle link I posted. It has minimum code. Good luck!

Comment: @yosh Thank you, 

<div class="wrapper_1">
 <div class="header">
  <div id="navigation">
   
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="content" id="potitions">
 </div>
 <div class="footer">
 </div>
</div>

This is my start. Well will post when I have finished everything

Answer (score 1):

For your IE problem, you're telling `#nav` to float left. There is no real need for that. I assume you were intending to apply it to the child elements. IE does have an issue with backgrounds only expanding to the height of the content. Other than the kinda-hacky solution of setting a height explicitly, I have no fix for that.

In firefox it's not enforcing the width of the body, so use a div around it to force the width to what you want.

Comment: Nothing happened when i changed #nav float.. I used div around it to force, yosh told me, but yeah.. does not work properly

Comment: Remove the body width too when trying these.

Comment: Well thanks anyways, I'm going to rewrite the code in proper way. And see what the results are now with this information in hand.

Comment: Good call. A little more advice: use css to set your widths, not the width attribute. Same with height. Generally speaking, if you can do it with css, do it. Also, you're currently using 70% and 35% for your td widths. Those add to more than 100%.

Comment: Thank you, did not notice it was 105%. I will make a clean version now and hope it will work out.

Answer (score 0):

Try `display: inline-block;`

Not sure as not tested.

Comment: You mean in style.css right? I changed all the display: block; to display: inline-block;. No difference though